# Add existing xcode project as subproject of another with pod and storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have a projectA that use cocoapod, it just works nice. It's not a library, just a regular IOS app.

Now i have projectB that use cocoapod too and i need to include projectA as a subproject. The goal is to load the storyboard from projectA when i press a button.

What i have try:

1. Importing the xcworkspace file from projectA, it just import the file, nothing else
2. Importing xcodeproj from projectA, i can see the projectA files but the storyboardA is not in the main bundle and complain when i try to load it.

   If i add the projectA.app as a dependencies in the build phase, the build process fail but i see no red flag, weird.

   I have try to drag and drop the projectA.app into the "Copy bundle ressource" but the storyboardA is still not found.

   I have try to drag and drop the storyboardA into "Copy bundle ressource", it works, yeah, storyboard found but the first controller of this storyboard is not found. That make me think i may not go the right way, i don't want to drag and drop every single file.

   I have try to create a Bundle and include the storyboard but it complain it can't find the controller into it.

   I have add ProjectA path in header search path, this seems to works when i write import "someheaderfromA.h" but doesn't resolve anything.

Can what i try to do be done or does i just waste my time ?

If it can be done, how ?

Thanks

Comment: @erick did you found some way to do the same ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have u resolved it? @Eric